# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Protecting Worklight Console with encrypted worklight.properties file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security, worklight-console

I have specified the following in worklight.properties:

```
console.username.enc=<encrypted string>
console.password.enc=<encrypted string>
```

in worklight.properties.

However, there is a warning message "**com.worklight.server.bundle.api.WorklightConfiguration getStringProperty Using empty value for configuration property 'console.password**' in SystemOut.log file.

It looks strange to me because there is no warning 'console.username' though I actually do not expect such warning will appear when I use '.enc' to specify the encrypted strings.

To investigate this problem, I have further conducted the following tests:

**Trial 1) Specify console.username.enc and console.password**

> Result: Worklight console can be successfully login without any warning message in SystemOut.log. So, it will not be due to encryption / decryption problem as console.username.enc can be successfully decrypted.

**Trial 2) Specify console.username and console.password.enc**

> Result: Same warning message (...Using empty value for configuration property 'console.password'...) appeared

**Trial 3) Specify console.username and console.password**

> Result: Worklight console can be successfully login.

**Trial 4) Remove console.username and console.password from worklight.properties**

> Result: Two warning messages - "Using empty value for configuration property 'console.username'.....'console.password') appeared

So, the problem seems like there is only problem in reading the value from 'console.password.enc' (but not 'console.username.enc') which sounds quite strange.

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Please be sure to mention if you are a customer or business partner so once the fix is delivered to 5.0.6.x we'll know how to contact you to to be able to get it. Thanks.

Comment: did your customer get the iFix? Can this question be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a defect and is fixed in Worklight 6.0.0.x and above. It is pending backporting to 5.0.6.x.  There is no workaround available.

If you are a customer or business partner of IBM and require this fix, you should open a PMR to make sure it will be delivered to you via an iFix release.